# How do I watch all keys in a data object in Vue 2

Tags: watch, vuejs2, vue.js

My data object:

```
data: {
    selected: {
        'type': null,
        'instrument': null
    },
```

My template:

```
<select v-model="selected['instrument']" @change="switchFilter('instrument', $event)">
    <option v-for="instrument in instruments" :value="instrument.value">@{{ instrument.text }}</option> 
</select>

<select v-model="selected['type']" @change="switchFilter('type', $event)">
    <option v-for="type in types" :value="type.value">@{{ type.text }}</option> 
</select>
```

How can I watch both selected indexes at the same time? I want to do something like this everytime any of the indexes updates:

```
watch: {
    selected: function(o, n) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to watch all data everywhere, you can can add a watch for `'$data'`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `deep` option provided by the [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) from vue. As stated in the docs:

> To also detect nested value changes inside Objects, you need to pass in deep: true in the options argument. Note that you don’t need to do so to listen for Array mutations.

You code will look like following:

```
watch: {
    'selected': {
        handler: function (val, oldVal) {
            console.log('watch 1', 'newval: ', val, '   oldVal:', oldVal)
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

I think you can do this:

```
watch: {
    $data: {
        handler: function(val, oldVal) {
            console.log(val)
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

Comment: I think this answer still adds a new angle. DRY and elegant. :)

Comment: @Anonymous - His answer is more than fine and not remotely unnecessary:  it shows it's possible to watch the built-in `data` object, which no other answer demonstrated.

Comment: Didn't know about the ```deep: true```, works great! Also very clean when you destruct the parameter object, like ```handler: function({ value1, value2 })``` (ES6). My only concern is that it is watching everything in $data. Anyone knows how to watch the destructed parameters only? Writing seperate watchers just don't feel DRY.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133894/vue-js-how-to-properly-watch-for-nested-data

Answer (score 11):

```
watch: {
  'selected.type': function (newSelectedType) {
    console.log(newSelectedType)
  },

  'selected.instrument': function (newSelectedinstrument) {
    console.log(newSelectedinstrument)
  }
}
```

If you are just trying to calculate a new data from `selected`, you can just use computed properties, since the data of Vue are reactive, the computed properties can also detect the changes of data.

---

If you want to use a single function to watch the entire object, you can use `$watch` with `deep: true`:

```
mounted () {
  this.$watch('$data.selected', this.onSelectedUpdate, { deep: true })
}
```

note that `'$data.selected'` is a string, Vue will parse it.

and in your methods:

```
onSelectedUpdate (newSelected) {
  console.log(newSelected)
}
```